# Allowing one sprite to move through another in Quintus

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, quintus-engine

I have a *Bumper* class extended from *Sprite*:

```
Q.Sprite.extend("Bumper", {

    init: function(p) {
        this._super(p, {gravity: 0});
        this.add("2d, ... //etc.
}
```

I have an *Enemy* class that should trigger a function when the **center** of the Bumper and of the Enemy collide.

I was thinking about doing something like this in my *Enemy* class :

```
this.on("bump.top, bump.bottom, bump.left, bump.right", function(collision) {
    if(collision.obj.isA("Bumper")) { 
        if (this.p.x == collision.obj.p.x && this.p.y == collision.obj.p.y) {
        //Do something
        }
    }
});
```

But for that I need the two sprites to move through one another. Is there a way to do that while still checking for collision ?